# Reading contet from stdin file using <file.txt in C, fopen is forbidden

Tags: c, stdin

i wanted to ask you, how to read from file using in C language:

```
your_program <file.txt

cat file.txt
Line one
Line two
Line three
```

i have something like that, but it is not working. Thanks a lot

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int vstup;
    input = getchar();


    while( input != '\n')
        printf("End of line!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting from your program?  What is the actual output?  You realize you made an infinite loop because `input` will never change after you first assign to it, right?

Comment: And how this is not working?

Comment: You have read only one character from your file.

Comment: [You might like to have a look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+read+from+file+using+in+C+language)

Comment: Also you might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `freopen()` to make `stdin` refer to the input file instead of the keyboard.

This can be used for input or output redirection.

In your case, do

```
freopen("file.txt", "r", stdin);
```

Now `stdin` is associated with the file `file.txt` and when you read using functions like `scanf()`, you are actually reading from `file.txt`.

`freopen()` will close the old stream (which is `stdin` here) "otherwise, the function behaves just like `fopen()`". It will return `NULL` if some error occurred. So you better check the value returned by `freopen()`.

Read more about `freopen()` [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/freopen.html) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/freopen).

And as others have pointed out, the code as you posted it is probably having an infinite loop as the value of `input` never changes inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

compile/link the proposed code into some file,  lets call that executable: `run`

when running the following proposed code, redirect 'stdin' from the input file

```
./run < file.txt
```

Here is the proposed code:

```
                     // <<-- document why a header is being included
#include <stdio.h>   // getchar(), EOF, printf()
//#include <stdlib.h>  <<-- don't include header files those contents are not used

int main( void )    // <<-- since the 'main()' parameters are not used, 
                    //      use this signature
{
    int input;      // <<-- 'getchar()' returns an integer and EOF is an integer
    while( (input = getchar() ) != EOF ) // <<-- input one char per loop until EOF
    {
        if( '\n' == input )              // is that char a newline?
        {
            printf("End of line!\n");    // yes, then print message
        }
    }
    return 0;
} // end function: main   <<-- document key items in your code
```